# sync local file with repo done by my collaborator who's working on the same file

Tags: git, github

say i have 2 person working on the repo and we're working on the same index.js file

i'm working for feature A on the same index.js and also make some new file in my local branch

on the other hand, my friend is working on feature B and he pushed the changes and merge it to main branch. will git pull delete my work on feature A and add the feature B to my local index.js file that is merged in the main repo?

or how do i update my local files up to date with the current main branch and still have my feature that i'm working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will not delete your work, even if you do something wrong git will warn you and try to prevent you from doing that.
You have to commit your changes and either run `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`, one will fetch and merge, another will fetch and rebase.

If you haven't committed your changes git will warn you and refuse to merge or rebase before you "either have committed your local changes or stashed them" (at least for conflicting files)

As for what will happen with index.js. Either you and your friends changes are in different parts of the files, and git can "auto-resolve" the conflict, otherwise you will get a conflict you will be asked to resolve. (when using `git status` it will give you a list of files you need to fix)

A conflict in the file will look something like this:

```
Content of file before either of your changes
<<<<<<< yours
your changes
=======
your friends changes
>>>>>>> theirs
More content of the file as it was before either of your changes
```

(See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented)

git is basically asking you what the file is supposed to look like after you have merged the changes of your friend and your changes together.

After you have resolved a conflict use `git add` to mark the conflict as resolved (which your console will tell you to do if you run `git status`).

After you have resolved all your conflicts use `git commit` to complete the merge/rebase (which `git status` also will tell you :P)

The best advice for getting through a merge with conflicts is basically, if in doubt what to do, run `git status` and it will tell you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

1. Commit your work and then merge the main branch into yours.
2. Commit your work and then rebase your branch onto the main branch.
3. If your code is not ready to commit you can stash your changes, merge/rebase the main changes, and then pop the stash.

```
git stash
git merge origin/main
git stash pop
```

Comment: by stashing it does it mean if the original index.js has 50 lines, my friend added 20 lines so now its 70, and by popping it, it will add my codes below the 70 lines?

Comment: provided you didn't make the changes in the same place your friend did, it should be able to merge it just fine. stashing creates a sort of virtual commit, so if there is a conflict, it will let you resolve it just like you normally would